# Passing reference in react native functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native and I am using reanimated-bottom sheet in my project and I want to control this from other functional component called as Comment.

in my main component I am passing the reference of the sheet as

```
<Comment ref={ref} />
```

but when I receive it in my comment component it says cant find variable ref

```js
     const Comment =({ref}) => {
....
      <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.panelButton}
               onPress={() => ref.current.snapTo(1)}>
                <Text>Cancel</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
...
}
```

all I want is to close the sheet from my comment component without changing it to class component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref` is predefined property so it won't be passed to the component.

You'd better use callback instead of passing ref.

```html
<Component ref={ref} onPressButton={() => { ref.current.snapTo(1) }} />
```

```js
const Comment =({ onPressButton }) => {
....
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.panelButton}
    onPress={onPressButton}>
      <Text>Cancel</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
....
}
```